# Expanding the Hyper-Parameter Search Grid in Caret

Tags: caret

I was wondering if there was a way to expand the hyper-parameter search within caret package or with slight modification. For example, evtree can currently only take alpha in caret but the evtree.control can take many more arguments. I doubt that I can just pass it through method = "evtree".

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number=10, repeats = 5,classProbs=TRUE,summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)


# Set up the cross-validated hyper-parameter search
EVTREE_GRID= expand.grid(pmutatemajor=c(0.2,0.2), pmutateminor=c(0.2,0.2), pcrossover=c(0.2,0.2),
                     psplit=c(0.2,0.2), pprune=c(0.2,0.2), minbucket=c(5L,10L), minsplit=c(15L,25L),
                     maxdepth=c(5L,15L),alpha=c(1L,5L))


EVTREE_fit_bayes <- function(pmutatemajor, pmutateminor, pcrossover, 
  psplit,pprune,minbucket,minsplit,maxdepth,alpha) {
    txt <- capture.output(
      mod <- train(Creditability~ ., data =XY_train,
                  method = "evtree",
                  preProc = c("center", "scale"),
                  metric = "AUC",
                  trControl = ctrl,
                  tuneGrid = EVTREE_GRID))

 list(Score = getTrainPerf(mod)[, "TrainAUC"], Pred)
 }


 library(rBayesianOptimization)
   EVTREE_Search <- BayesianOptimization(EVTREE_fit_bayes,

             bounds = list(pmutatemajor=c(0.2,0.2), pmutateminor=c(0.2,0.2), pcrossover=c(0.2,0.2), 
                           psplit=c(0.2,0.2), pprune=c(0.2,0.2), minbucket=c(5L,10L), 
                           minsplit=c(15L,25L), maxdepth=c(5L,15L), alpha=c(1L,5L)),

             init_grid_dt =NULL, 
             init_points =10, 
             n_iter = 10,
             acq = "ucb", 
             kappa =1, 
             eps = 0.0,
             verbose = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can [create your own model](https://topepo.github.io/caret/using-your-own-model-in-train.html) so basically you redefine the parameters for evtree, basically redefining the [existing one for evtree](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/models/files/evtree.R), the elements of the list to change are under parameters, grid and fit (where you pass in evtree.control) :

```
evtree_ext <- list(label = "Tree Models from Genetic Algorithms",
                  library = c("evtree"),
                  loop = NULL,
                  type = c('Regression', 'Classification'),
                  parameters = data.frame(parameter = c("maxdepth","alpha"),
                                          class = rep('numeric',2),
                                          label = c('maxdepth','alpha')),
                  grid = function(x, y, len = NULL, search = "grid") {
                    if(search == "grid") {
                      out <- data.frame(alpha = seq(1, 3, length = len),maxdepth=seq(1,20,len=len)) 
                    } else {
                      out <- data.frame(alpha = runif(len, min = 1, max = 5),maxdepth=sample(1:20,len=len))
                    }
                    out
                  },
                  fit = function(x, y, wts, param, lev, last, classProbs, ...){
                    dat <- if(is.data.frame(x)) x else as.data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
                    dat$.outcome <- y
                    theDots <- list(...)

                    if(any(names(theDots) == "control"))
                    {
                      theDots$control$alpha <- param$alpha 
                      ctl <- theDots$control
                      theDots$control <- NULL
                    } else ctl <- evtree::evtree.control(alpha = param$alpha,maxdepth=param$alpha)

                    ## pass in any model weights
                    if(!is.null(wts)) theDots$weights <- wts

                    modelArgs <- c(list(formula = as.formula(".outcome ~ ."),
                                        data = dat,
                                        control = ctl),
                                   theDots)

                    out <- do.call(evtree::evtree, modelArgs)
                    out
                  },
                  levels = function(x) x$obsLevels,
                  predict = function(modelFit, newdata, submodels = NULL) {
                    if(!is.data.frame(newdata)) newdata <- as.data.frame(newdata, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
                    predict(modelFit, newdata)
                    },
                  prob = function(modelFit, newdata, submodels = NULL) {
                    if(!is.data.frame(newdata)) newdata <- as.data.frame(newdata, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
                    predict(modelFit, newdata, type = "prob")
                    },
                  tags = c("Tree-Based Model", "Implicit Feature Selection", "Accepts Case Weights"),
                  sort = function(x) x[order(x[,1]),])
```

Using an example (sorry not familiar with this package, might be nonsense):

```
library(MASS)
library(caret)
library(evtree)
library(rBayesianOptimization)

mod <- train(type~ ., data =Pima.tr,method=evtree_ext,
tuneGrid=data.frame(alpha=c(1,2),maxdepth=c(5,10)),
trControl=trainControl(method="cv",number=2))

mod$results

  alpha maxdepth Accuracy     Kappa  AccuracySD    KappaSD
1     1        5    0.715 0.3511444 0.007071068 0.04724272
2     2       10    0.725 0.3273370 0.007071068 0.01357389
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Im going to try running the Bayesian optimization algorithm.

Comment: you're welcome .. happy modeling :)